# Последовательность С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Бесконечная числовая последовательность задана с помощью формулы ее k-го элемента:

**Ak = k!*2^k**, где k = 1, 2, 3,...

Найти сумму N первых элементов этой последовательности по модулю M.

Первая строка входного потока содержит два целых числа N - количество членов последовательности (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^4) и M - модуль (2 ≤ M ≤ 10^9).

В выходной поток вывести сумму N первых элементов заданной последовательности по модулю M.

Пример входного потока: 5 10
Пример выходного потока: 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
long fact (long v)
{
  int z=1;
  for (long i=1;i<=v;i++)
  {
    z*=i;
  }
  return z;
}
int main()
{
  long n,m,elem,sum=0;
  cin >> n >> m;
  for (long i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    elem=fact(i)*pow(2,i);
    sum+=elem;
  }
  cout << sum%m;
  return 0;
}
```

Проходит только 1 тест. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=910

Comment: Не пытаться решать задачу в лоб. Ваша наивная попытка вычислять `% m` только в самом конце обречена на провал.

Comment: `pow(2,i)` - сразу мимо. `pow` работает с дробными числами, и при больших `i` будут серьезные проблемы с точностью. Вместо этого нужно возводить в степень циклом. Дальше, для хоть сколько-нибудь больших `n`, наивное "почитать сумму, а потом взять от нее модуль" не сработает - числа слишком большие, в `long` не влезут.

Comment: Вместо этого нужно применять модуль чаще. Скажем, после каждого умножения (`*=`) при вычислении факториала делать `z %= m;`. Аналогично после умножения при возведении в степень, и аналогично после каждого сложения при вычислении суммы. За счет этого не придется работать с огромными числами, а ответ не поменяется. Если после этого размера переменных все равно не хватит, попробуйте `long long` вместо `long`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Да, проблемы с `pow(2,i)` действительно начнутся, когда `i` выйдет за диапазон экспоненты `double`. И проблемы будут не "с точностью", а со всем вообще, ибо это полный вылет за пределы диапазона `double`. Но пока такого вылета не произошло, в придерживающихся IEEE754 реализациях `pow(2,i)` обязан давать *точный* результат.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Сделал, не проходит теперь тесты на время даже на простых примерах. Хотя если проверять локально, то ответы правильные

Comment: @AnT Может и так, но после [Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) я как-то не особенно доверяю `pow`...

Comment: @Max *"не проходит теперь тесты на время"* Тогда сделайте вот что. Вместо того, чтобы пересчитывать факториал и степень для каждого члена, этот член можно получить, домножив предыдущий на `2*i`, как в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда не задумывались о том, что 10000! - это **очень** большое число, как и 2 в десятитысячной степени?

Надо *все время* работать по модулю `M`, примерно так (не компилировал, просто показать идею - набросал на коленке). `unsigned long long` нужен, поскольку при ваших значениях легко вылететь за пределы `int`.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    unsigned long long sum = 2, term = 2;
    for(int k = 2; k <= N; ++k)
    {
        term = (term * 2 * k) % M;
        sum = (sum + term) %M;
    }
    cout << sum%M << endl;
}
```

P.S. Я тут прикинул - для `N = 10000` эта сумма - примерно 5.6787516480462*10<sup>38669</sup>.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Странно, на значениях, что вбиваю вручную, причём на всех, работает отлично. Но на онлайн-проверке по-прежнему проходит 1 тест, при этом на время проверки пройдены успешно.

Comment: Ну что я могу вам сказать? Вот для 10000 и 1000000000 результат моей программы - 909349562. Вот результат вычисления в Wolfram Matematica `Mod[Sum[k!*2^k, {k, 1, 10000}], 1000000000]`: 909349562. Для 999999999 - 678847984... Чем я еще могу помочь?...

Comment: Напишу администратору сайта.. Возможно действительно у них что-то.

Comment: Но для чисел 1 1, 1 2 неверно, но это легко исправимо

Comment: @Max Для 1 1 - бессмысленно (для M=1 всегда 0, потому на M и ограничение >= 2); для 1 2 - согласен,     `cout << sum%M << endl;`, спасибо!

Comment: 5.6787516480462*10^38669 - действительно много, тогда как атомов в видимой вселенной от 4*10^79 до 4*10^81 по разным оценкам.)

Comment: @Harry задача прошла все тесты, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Урррряяяяя!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

С++ пересечение массивов (там ответить не могу):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int>::iterator intersect(vector<int> a1, vector<vector<int>> a, size_t& n, vector<int>*& p, vector<int>::iterator* j = nullptr)
{
    vector<int> r;
    if (++n >= a.size()) {
        if (p && j) {
            for (vector<int>::iterator k = p->begin(); k != *j; k++)
                r.push_back(*k);
            p = new vector<int>(r);
            return p->end();
        }
        p = &r;
        return r.begin();
    }
    p = &r;
    r.resize(std::min(a1.size(), a[n].size()));

    sort(a[n].begin(), a[n].end(), greater<int>());

    vector<int>::iterator i = set_intersection(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a[n].begin(), a[n].end(), r.begin(), greater <int>());

    return intersect(r, a, n, p, &i);
}

int main()
{ 
    vector<vector<int>> a = { {1,2,3},{4,3,5},{7,8,3} };

    size_t n = 0;
    vector<int>* p = nullptr;
    sort(a[0].begin(), a[0].end(), greater<int>());
    vector<int>::iterator i = intersect(a[0], a, n, p);
    if (!p) return 1;
    for (vector<int>::iterator j = p->begin(); j != i; j++)
        cout << *j << " ";
    delete p;
    char c;
    cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```